# Are Git's pack files deltas rather than snapshots?

Tags: git, version-control, internals

One of the key differences between Git and most other version control systems is that the others tend to store commits as a series of deltas - changesets between one commit and the next. This seems logical, since it's the smallest possible amount of information to store about a commit. But the longer the commit history gets, the more calculation it takes to compare ranges of revisions.

By contrast, Git stores a **complete snapshot of the whole project in each revision**. The reason this doesn't make the repo size grow dramatically with each commit is each file in the project is stored as a file in the Git subdirectory, named for the hash of its contents. So if the contents haven't changed, the hash hasn't changed, and the commit just points to the same file. And there are other optimizations as well.

All this made sense to me until I stumbled on [this information about pack files](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles), into which Git puts data periodically to save space:

> In order to save that space, Git
>   utilizes the packfile. This is a
>   format where Git will only save the
>   part that has changed in the second
>   file, with a pointer to the file it is
>   similar to.

**Isn't this basically going back to storing deltas? If not, how is it different? How does this avoid subjecting Git to the same problems other version controls systems have?**

For example, Subversion uses deltas, and rolling back 50 versions means undoing 50 diffs, whereas with Git you can just grab the appropriate snapshot. Unless git also stores 50 diffs in the packfiles... is there some mechanism that says "after some small number of deltas, we'll store a whole new snapshot" so that we don't pile up too large a changeset? How else might Git avoid the disadvantages of deltas?

Comment: See [pack-format.txt](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt) and [pack-heuristics.txt](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-heuristics.txt) in the documentation.

Comment: GIT uses snapshots rather than deltas to store its data. This makes Git faster and more efficient than CVS.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Summary:
Git’s pack files are carefully constructed to effectively use disk caches and
provide “nice” access patterns for common commands and for reading recently referenced
objects.

---

Git’s pack file
format is quite flexible (see [Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt;h=1803e64e465fa4f8f0fe520fc0fd95d0c9def5bd;hb=HEAD),
or [The Packfile](http://book.git-scm.com/7_the_packfile.html) in [The Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/index.html)).
The pack files store objects in two main
ways: “undeltified” (take the raw object data and deflate-compress
it), or “deltified” (form a delta against some other object then
deflate-compress the resulting delta data). The objects stored in
a pack can be in any order (they do not (necessarily) have to be
sorted by object type, object name, or any other attribute) and
deltified objects can be made against any other suitable object of the same type.

Git’s [*pack-objects*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-objects.html) command uses several [heuristics](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt;h=103eb5d989349c8e7e0147920b2e218caba9daf9;hb=HEAD) to
provide excellent [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) for common
commands. These heuristics control both the selection of base
objects for deltified objects and the order of the objects. Each
mechanism is mostly independent, but they share some goals.

Git does form long chains of delta compressed objects, but the
heuristics try to make sure that only “old” objects are at the ends of 
the long chains. The delta base cache (whose size is controlled by the
`core.deltaBaseCacheLimit` configuration variable) is automatically
used and can greatly reduce the number of “rebuilds” required for
commands that need to read a large number of objects (e.g. `git log
-p`).

## Delta Compression Heuristic

A typical Git repository stores a very large number of objects, so
it can not reasonably compare them all to find the pairs (and
chains) that will yield the smallest delta representations.

The delta base selection heuristic is based on the idea that the
good delta bases will be found among objects with similar filenames
and sizes. Each type of object is processed separately (i.e. an
object of one type will never be used as the delta base for an
object of another type).

For the purposes of delta base selection, the objects are sorted (primarily) by
filename and then size. A window into this sorted list is used to limit
the number of objects that are considered as potential delta bases.
If a “good enough”<sup>1</sup> delta representation is not found for an object
among the objects in its window, then the object will not be delta
compressed.

The size of the window is controlled by the `--window=` option of
`git pack-objects`, or the `pack.window` configuration variable. The
maximum depth of a delta chain is controlled by the `--depth=`
option of `git pack-objects`, or the `pack.depth` configuration
variable. The `--aggressive` option of `git gc` greatly enlarges
both the window size and the maximum depth to attempt to create
a smaller pack file.

The filename sort clumps together the objects for entries with with
identical names (or at least similar endings (e.g. `.c`)). The size
sort is from largest to smallest so that deltas that remove data are
preferred to deltas that add data (since removal deltas have shorter
representations) and so that the earlier, larger objects (usually
newer) tend to be represented with plain compression.

<sup>1</sup>
What qualifies as “good enough” depends on the size of the object in question and its potential delta base as well as how deep its resulting delta chain would be.

## Object Ordering Heuristic

Objects are stored in the pack files in a “most recently referenced”
order. The objects needed to reconstruct the most recent history are
placed earlier in the pack and they will be close together. This
usually works well for OS disk caches.

All the commit objects are sorted by commit date (most recent first)
and stored together. This placement and ordering optimizes the disk
accesses needed to walk the history graph and extract basic commit
information (e.g. `git log`).

The tree and blob objects are stored starting with the tree from the
first stored (most recent) commit. Each tree is processed in a depth
first fashion, storing any objects that have not already been
stored. This puts all the trees and blobs required to reconstruct
the most recent commit together in one place. Any trees and blobs that
have not yet been saved but that are required for later commits are
stored next, in the sorted commit order.

The final object ordering is slightly affected by the delta base selection
in that if an object is selected for delta representation and its base object
has not been stored yet, then its base object is stored immediately before the
deltified object itself. This prevents likely disk cache misses due to the
non-linear access required to read a base object that would have “naturally” been
stored later in the pack file.

Answer (score 8):

The use of delta storage in the pack file is just an implementation detail. At that level, Git doesn't know why or how something changed from one revision to the next, rather it just knows that blob B is pretty similar to blob A except for these changes C. So it will only store blob A and changes C (if it chooses to do so - it could also choose to store blob A and blob B).

When retrieving objects from the pack file, the delta storage is not exposed to the caller. The caller still sees complete blobs. So, Git works the same way it always has without the delta storage optimisation.

Comment: All of this is equally true of deltas stored by most other version control systems though...

Comment: The relationships between the blobs when compressed may have **nothing** to do with the relationships suggested/implied by the revision history.

Comment: I understand that this is not exposed to the caller, but still, to retrieve a given hash, Git may have to take a blob and apply a changeset; it doesn't have a true snapshot, right? So what sets this apart from SVN at that point - is it that it never has to stack up a large number of deltas to get to a particular point in history because it limits how many deltas is stacks on a blob?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's different from SVN, because I'm not really sure how SVN works inside. But I can point out that it's different from Darcs (and the Darcs theory of patches) in that the pack files have nothing to do with how git merges branches. Git reconstructs the snapshot of the revisions it's merging, it also reconstructs snapshots of any older revisions it needs to merge, and then figures out what to do. Darcs, on the other hand, stores patches, and combines them when you need a working directory, and it can create different working directories based on different sets of patches.

Comment: Git *does* limit how many deltas may need to be applied to regenerate an object (and btw delta representation is just as useful for trees as blobs) which is the `--depth` parameter to `git pack-objects`. Some looking at what actually gets packed also suggests Git requires a delta to be really quite small for it to be worth using instead of the compressed blob.

Comment: IMHO, This is not at all an answer to the question (I examined the first version of Q to be sure). The question *is* about implementation details, not about what is exposed to caller. Specifically, Q is a concern that pack files might introduce performance issues seen with alternative source control systems, by making it necessary for git [internally] to process multiple previous packs per queried file [deltas], instead of being able to grab all needed info [at least for one file] in one place.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Historically, some questions got [*merged*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) which means the answers from two different questions got combined into the answers to one question. It seems like this might have been one of those cases. But it was 8 years ago, so I'm not going to claim I remember what the question was when I wrote the answer. :)

Comment: @GregHewgill - ahh, that would explain it. I didn't know that was sometimes done, and your answer does seem specifically tailored to a somewhat different question. Thanks for enlightening me on that possibility. i'll keep that in mind before commenting on old answers.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in "[What are git's thin packs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584190/6309)"

> Git does deltification only in packfiles

I detailed the delta encoding used for pack files in "[Is the git binary diff algorithm (delta storage) standardized?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/6309)".
See also "[When and how does git use deltas for storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496599/6309)".

Note that the **`core.deltaBaseCacheLimit`** config which controls the default size for the pack file will soon be bumped from 16MB to 96MB, for Git 2.0.x/2.1 (Q3 2014).

See [commit 4874f54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4874f544f1574a55d787339a6455f524768c1b5d) by  David Kastrup (May 2014):

#### Bump core.deltaBaseCacheLimit to 96m

> The default of 16m causes serious thrashing for large delta chains combined with large files.

> Here are some benchmarks (pu variant of `git blame`):

```
time git blame -C src/xdisp.c >/dev/null
```

> for a repository of Emacs repacked with `git gc --aggressive` (v1.9, resulting in a window size of 250) located on an SSD drive.
> The file in question has about 30000 lines, 1Mb of size, and a history with about
> 2500 commits.

```
16m (previous default):
  real  3m33.936s
  user  2m15.396s
  sys   1m17.352s

96m:
  real  2m5.668s
  user  1m50.784s
  sys   0m14.288s
```

---

This is further optimized with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), where "[`git index-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7e65b51e53bd43e937bd6238b9ee81412d9080c/Documentation/git-index-pack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-index-pack))</sup> learned to resolve deltified objects with greater parallelism.

See [commit f08cbf6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f08cbf60fe11507b5ff722ceae95dfb86ce654ee) (08 Sep 2020), and [commit ee6f058](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee6f058384aa61ec175de9e45f413f209c6bf1dc), [commit b4718ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4718cae51f9630f2901c452ca4e4dfbf68f47ef), [commit a7f7e84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7f7e84a496d194ceeeba9827d17c4c206932d2b), [commit 46e6fb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46e6fb1e4462fa4363b3d6ace827140dd1c4bc39), [commit fc968e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc968e26c201a63d4d75cae550ecf0447c82920f), [commit 009be0d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/009be0d26d579c61dd7c7819e77173676c3ce007) (24 Aug 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b7e65b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7e65b51e53bd43e937bd6238b9ee81412d9080c), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`index-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f08cbf60fe11507b5ff722ceae95dfb86ce654ee): make quantum of work smaller
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> Currently, when index-pack resolves deltas, it does not split up delta trees into threads: each delta base root (an object that is not a `REF_DELTA` or `OFS_DELTA)` can go into its own thread, but all deltas on that root (direct or indirect) are processed in the same thread.
>
> This is a problem when a repository contains a large text file (thus, delta-able) that is modified many times - delta resolution time during fetching is dominated by processing the deltas corresponding to that text file.
>
> This patch contains a solution to that.
> When cloning using
>
> ```
> git -c core.deltabasecachelimit=1g clone \
>   https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/vulkan-cts
> ```
>
> on my laptop, clone time improved from 3m2s to 2m5s (using 3 threads, which is the default).
>
> The solution is to have a global work stack. This stack contains delta bases (objects, whether appearing directly in the packfile or generated by delta resolution, that themselves have delta children) that need to be processed; whenever a thread needs work, it peeks at the top of the stack and processes its next unprocessed child. If a thread finds the stack empty, it will look for more delta base roots to push on the stack instead.
>
> The main weakness of having a global work stack is that more time is spent in the mutex, but profiling has shown that most time is spent in the resolution of the deltas themselves, so this shouldn't be an issue in practice. In any case, experimentation (as described in the clone command above) shows that this patch is a net improvement.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), you have more details about the format.

See [commit 7b77f5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b77f5a13effd01c40b3b354d93749ece79e0acc) (29 Dec 2020) by [Martin Ågren (`none`)](https://github.com/none).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 16a8055](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16a8055daebdf95ca4bb97e3efe07e87f588767e), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pack-format.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b77f5a13effd01c40b3b354d93749ece79e0acc): document sizes at start of delta data
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ross Light</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Martin Ågren</sup>

> We document the delta data as a set of instructions, but forget to document the two sizes that precede those instructions: the size of the base object and the size of the object to be reconstructed.
> Fix this omission.
>
> Rather than cramming all the details about the encoding into the running text, introduce a separate section detailing our "size encoding" and refer to it.

`technical/pack-format` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7b77f5a13effd01c40b3b354d93749ece79e0acc/Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt#L58-L69):

> ### Size encoding
>
> This document uses the following "size encoding" of non-negative
> integers: From each byte, the seven least significant bits are
> used to form the resulting integer.
> As long as the most significant
> bit is 1, this process continues; the byte with MSB 0 provides the
> last seven bits.
>
> The seven-bit chunks are concatenated.
> Later
> values are more significant.
>
> This size encoding should not be confused with the "offset encoding",
> which is also used in this document.

`technical/pack-format` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7b77f5a13effd01c40b3b354d93749ece79e0acc/Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt#L88-L91):

> The delta data starts with the size of the base object and the
> size of the object to be reconstructed. These sizes are
> encoded using the size encoding from above.
>
> The remainder of
> the delta data is a sequence of instructions to reconstruct the object