# What's the meaning of git's snapshot of a file?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I'm reading [git basics](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)

> Git thinks of its data more like a set of snapshots of a miniature
>   filesystem

I could not understanding the meaning of snapshot of git. Does git store the entire file content in each snapshot/version? For example,
version 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        printf("hello, world");
        return 0;
}
```

In version 2 I added an extra line to the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        printf("hello, world");
        printf("hello, git");
        return 0;
}
```

Will git store the entire content rather than store only the difference(`printf("hello, git")`) between these two versions as svn etc?

If it is, what's the point?

Comment: *Will git store the entire content rather than store only the difference(printf("hello, git")) between these two versions as svn etc?* Yes, but it may eventually store those two versions efficiently. *[...] what's the point?* Contrary to SVN, you don't have to "apply" a sequence of patches to get a particular version.

Comment: One more useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files/8198276#8198276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will **git store the entire content** rather than store only the difference(printf("hello, git")) between these two versions as svn etc?

Git stores **the entire contents of a file**. But it takes no extra space when the file didn't change.

Read this brilliant answer about the Git pack file format: [Are Git's pack files deltas rather than snapshots?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5576688/2790048)

#### About SHA1

Files (and other stuff) are stored in a form of a "blob". Each sequence of bytes has its own sha1-code, which is pretty unique for it.

The following is true about SHA1:

1. SHA1 calculation for a file gives the same result at any time, OS, Git version or implementation.
2. Files with different names or paths but equal contents will always have equal SHA1-s.
3. If two files have different SHA1-s, they are not equal with probability of 1.
4. If two files have equal SHA1-s, they are equal with probability of around 1 - 1 / 2<sup>400</sup> (as I remember) which is pretty much like 1.

#### What benefits this system gives

1. Revisions can be compared for equality very quick. No file contents are checked, just their SHA1-s.

   - When you push/pull, only changed files are transmitted.
   - Checking status of current changes is done in a moment.
   - Lets you track N files with equal contents, taking only place of a single file in Git.
2. Changing the revision in your working tree is very quick.

   - Without applying consecutive patches
   - You can exclude commits from a branch, pull them to another branch, change their order.

#### About diff (and git diff):

You may have noticed that git indeed shows a diff of text files, pointing out the added and removed lines. This is done with the [diff utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) for your convenience. This also helps collect contribution statistics. And this is used for resolving merge conflicts. But nevertheless Git treats and stores text (and binary) files as single blobs.

#### Exclusion with [git add --patch](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

There is a way to force Git to break text files to chunks when staging changes. This may be useful for very large files, but pretty useless for small ones.

```
git add --patch
```

> Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work tree and add them to the index. This gives the user a chance to review the difference before adding modified contents to the index.

#### These are my favourite illustrations about Git from [Pro Git](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Will git store the entire content rather than store only the difference? [... and if so] what's the point?

Yes.  That's what makes constructing good git histories so much simpler, and counterintuitively enough it also results in better compression efficiency.

(edit: relegate lotsa pedantry and elaboration to the revision history)