# Which factors contribute to size of git repo

Tags: git, size, commit, git-squash

I would like to know which factors contribute to the size of a git repo, Except the data of course.

Does having a long history means a big repo?
Does having many branches have some affect on it?

Also how do you guys handle your commits? 
I read that each commit should have at least one logical unit of change added to it.
I know that commits can be squashed by rebasing before pushing. (Never rebase published of course).

So i don't know if i should squash them or not. Because i don't know if it makes any change to the size or not.

Thanks

Comment: For git workflows: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/ Branches are merely pointers to commits, so they don't take up too much space. Commits with changes to many files do take up more space, and a longer history often correlates to more commits, so that often correlates to a bigger repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A repo itself will see its size vary mainly because of the nature of the data put in it: binary data will be less efficiently stored than non-binary data, and is generally bigger anyway.

A repo in use (locally clone) can see its size vary depending on the last `gc` and `repack`: See [`git gc --aggressive` vs `git repack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720432/6309). [Packfiles are where deltification is done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978239/6309).

As for the commits, read "[Utter Disregard for Git Commit History](http://zachholman.com/posts/git-commit-history/)".

> These are two extremes of viewing what the core unit of change is for the respective project.
>
> - From Git’s perspective — likely because of the ease of use inside a mailing list approach — a single atomic commit makes most sense.
> - From GitHub’s perspective, individual commits become less valuable because the atomic unit is the pull request
>
> In both cases, more historical context on a change can be easily found by going back to the mailing list discussion or the pull request conversation.