# Tech stack required to understand Git source code

Tags: git

I'm interested in understanding the Git source code and maybe someday contribute to it.

I understand Git source code is build on:

1. languages such as C, Shell, Perl, Python, C++, TCL

2) Technology such as HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, etc

I was just wondering, is there anything else that are pre-requisite to understanding the Git source code?

Comment: Why don't you just start looking at it? When you find something you don't understand, do some research.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I just want to have a general direction of where to go before getting started

Comment: The general direction is to just start looking at it, then go from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the patch submitting process, other sources can help understanding the Git code base.

- the protocols used: [Git on the Server - The Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)
- the documentations like:

  - [Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/CodingGuidelines)
  - [Diff formats](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/diff-format.txt)
  - [git thin packs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978239/6309)
  - [git binary diff format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/6309)
  - ...

But another approach is to study how Git was re-implemented in other languages: those are often a subset of Git, less intimidating and quite educational.

- [packfiles have been re-implemented in Go](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/implementing_gits-compression_algorithm_in_go/),
- [Other Git functions have been written in Go as well](https://github.com/chimeracoder/gitgo),
- A [Git http-backend is available in Go](https://github.com/jaxi/git-http-backend),
- [the Git format and protocol have been code in OCaml](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-git)
- [Git.js proposes a Javascript implementation](http://readwrite.com/2011/08/06/gitjs-a-git-implementation-in/) (also [done with Gitlet](http://gitlet.maryrosecook.com/))
- ...

So if the [original git/git codebase](https://github.com/git/git) seems complex, you can compare and contrast its implementation with some of those listed above, to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 6):

git is written in almost entirely `C` and bash scripts. if you want to contribute, look in their extremely extensive documentation: [Documentation/SubmittingPatches](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/SubmittingPatches)