# Changing the Git username

Tags: windows, git, github

I use Git GNU bash, version 4.3.42(5)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
 windows 8.1 pro.
I gave it a username at the very beginning by typing the command:
    git config --global user.name"xyz"
but then when i've got to Github, this username was already taken, so i tried to change my Git username to be the same as the one Github. Typing the same command
then typing :
    git config --list 
but it keeps showing the old username, i've tried even to uninstall it, and then retype the same command, but it's the same issue.
Someone maybe can tell me how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at both the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory for global settings and also `.git/config` in a specific project for override values.

In Windows there may be some [extra steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766147/no-git-repository-folder-showing-using-windows-7) to view these files.

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion made above was great, but i managed differently to solve the problem :

I went to the Git GUI, then Edit, Then options and there i've found different button to change the username. That was successful.