# github commits that show full name instead of username

Tags: github, git-bash

I usually commit in github using **gitbash**.

When I commit it shows my username.

My **professor** asked me to submit my project that shows my **full name** in commit **details**.

I tried some solutions by editing **.gitconfig** file in windows.

I also tried some solutions from **Stack Overflow** like following:

```
git config --global user.name "name"
git config --global user.email "email"
```

and

```
git config user.name "name"
git config user.email "email"
```

but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Git username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063493/changing-the-git-username)

Comment: I tried some solution that doesn't work out, for this reason I post the question

Comment: If you put your full name for "name" field, then Full name will be show in commit details.

Comment: i tried that but still no result come

Comment: you can get the current setting with `git config user.name`, this should print "name". If it does not work, what doesnt and how did you test that?

Comment: actually when i type `git config user.name` it shows my full name

but when i commit , in github it shows my user name

Comment: same issue. When you look at `git history` it will show your *full name* but Github shours your *username*. Annoying :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```