# Creating .git file on windows

Tags: git

I am working on school project and they require .git file included.

I am running currently windows.
I have used git app to commit my repositary on github.

How can i create a .git file?
I fail to find any solution for  this.

Is there a way how to do so on windows?

Comment: If your project is a Git repository then it has a `.git` already. It is a directory, not a file, and I think by default it is marked 'hidden' on Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No .git repository folder showing, using windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766147/no-git-repository-folder-showing-using-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Check the repo folder you committed, using show *hidden files* on windows explorer, there should already be a `.git` folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      cd my_source_dir
      git init
      git add .
      git commit -m "initial commit"
```

And now you can access it from

```
     git clone /path/to/my_source_dir new_tree_name
```

Comment: but how do i add .git file? I mean i am sending zip file on the school server that has to contain .git file ,

Comment: .git files are automatically generated, but they are hidden.