# Cmder showing " origin -> master " when cd Desktop or any other project

Tags: git, cmder

`C: \Users\ETHan\Desktop (master -> origin)`

Is this an issue and should I be worried? I do not recall ever seeing this when CD to my desktop before but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for any `.git` subfolder in:

- `C:\` or
- `C:\Users` or (more likely)
- `C:\users\EThan`
- `C:\users\EThan\Desktop`

If you don't intent to version your full user account content, you can delete thatksubfolder.

Comment: I do not see any yet but would it matter if I have some projects on my desktop?

Comment: @ETHan Yes, because some projects would be conflated into one giant Git repository. Mae sure you have the latest Git for Windows installed, and then, in `C:\Users\ETHan\Desktop`, do a `git config --show-config --show-scope -l` (look for "local" lines), as well as a `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`: that should give you the folder where the `.git` is.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Let me try this and I will report back. I think one time I used ```git init``` when I was in my desktop directory instead of a project folder and I think that is what is causing my issue.

Comment: @ETHan Than would explain your current prompt indeed.

Comment: so I ran the code in cmder and It returned ```C:\Users\ETHan\Desktop (master -> origin)
λ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
C:/Users/ETHan/Desktop```

I have searched through my desktop and I do not have a .git folder. I do however have git folders for a few projects which are currently sitting on the desktop ( C:/Users/ETHan/Desktop/Project1/git ... for example). I am not sure if I am getting this issue because of those git folders, or if I used ```git init``` on my desktop by accident

Comment: @ETHan Beware, on Windows, those .git subfolder are **hidden**: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323211/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323211/6309

Comment: Okay so after reading this and running the command to set the hiding of .gits to false, it still doesnt show it so I cd into my .git directory from my desktop and I am now here ```C:\Users\ETHan\Desktop\.git (master -> origin)``` . Do you know of a way for me to delete this folder from here?

Comment: @ETHan Yes, open a CMD, and type `cd C:\Users\ETHan\Desktop` then `rmdir /S .git`