# Where does git store changes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Reading answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082445/where-does-git-store-files), we learn that changes in git are stored in `.git` that resides in the project's root directory. But in a normal Rails app I cannot see `.git` anywhere.

Comment: Did you create git repository in this project's main directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, we have a folder called `/.git` -> this is built when we use the `git add .` & `git commit` commands. Here's a picture of it for you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you and to this http://superuser.com/a/430265 I realized it was my editor that choose to not show it. (Mac doesn't natively show hidden files.)

Answer (score 2):

`.git` directory is created by git, not rails.

If you don't use git to manage your rails project, there will no `.git` of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `rails new app --git` rails will not create a `.git` directory.

Usually the .git directory is a hidden folder. Under linux and mac you can show all folders and files with the `ls -la` command.