# Git repository folder

Tags: git

I am new in learning programming, and got stuck while learning Git. From what I have learned so far, if we want to use Git locally, we may first need to create a folder, and then create a Git repository inside with the `git init` command.

Are those files that wanted to be kept track of necessary to be in the same folder as the `.git` directory?

Comment: The location of the `.git` folder is the root of the repository. So yes, they need to be in a folder in the same context

Comment: Yes, the `.git` folder lives in the root directory of the repository.  Files that you want to track can live in that root directory or in subdirectories.

Comment: It's theoretically possible that the `.git` directory is separate from the files to be kept track of, but unless you know what you're doing I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the `.git` folder _is the repository_.

Comment: I think your question is addressed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3082740).