# GIT commit doesn't push to repository?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have just set up GIT source control inside Visual Studio which loads a solution in a folder linked to my GIT repository on BitBucket.

Im still getting my head around this and wondered if anyone could shine some light on a few questions:

- When I change a file in VS2010 it appears as you would expect in the "GIT Pending changes" window. When I click "Commit" on here with a comment, am I right in thinking that these changes will be committed to my local version of the repository until I use "Push".
- **If this is the case, can I then UNDO commits before I run PUSH**? Seems silly not to run push automatically otherwise.
- When I undo a files change "Undo pending change for file", it still remains in the list as "Modified" despite being identical to the server version in a compare. WIll it still overwrite it with the same file??! Or is this just a bug in VS2010 plugin?

Thanks for anybody that could help, I really want to try to wrap my head around GIT for my next projects' SCM!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, `git commit` simply commits changes to your local repository, while `git push` sends changes to a remote repository.  You're free to use `git` to track changes in a local directory without ever linking it to a remote repository.  This is one reason why I like `git` and other distribution version control systems.

You can certainly undo commits in your local repository before pushing it to a remote repository.  [This chapter](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) of the git book discusses this topic in more detail.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that now. Undoing a local commit was my main concern. Just got to remember to keep pushing!

Answer (score 1):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745097/1073300 have a link to a nice picture explaining git data transport commands, including `git commit` and `git push`.

Comment: BOnus points for the diagram, helped me understand the flow a bit better :)