# How to update GIT remote repository?

Tags: git, commit, pull

I have just switched from subversion to GIT and found out it is much faster.

I have a problem - on one location / computer I change file, delete dir,... and commit it Everything is OK (If I define new GIT on another folder everything is correct). On another location I pull and nothing happens - deleted files stays, no changes is made etc...

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: O BTW ... I work in NetBeans...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`commit` only commits to your local repository. I think you are looking for `push` to send it to the main repo?

See: [What are the differences between "git commit" and "git push"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745076/what-is-the-difference-between-git-commit-and-git-push) for a great diagram explaining how Git works.

Obviously this is different to what you are used to, whereby there is only one centralized repository; now you have your own local repo, hence Git being a distributed system...also partially why it is so much faster for you!

Answer (score 2):

While it is not an answer to your specific question, I would suggest this link:

[Git Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html)

for review. The author of the page (Lars Vogel) put together a very good beginner's guide to Git, and when I can't remember a specific option/parameter for what I am trying to do, this is what I 99% of the time refer to for help. For working with remote repos, you'll want to read through sections 11 and 12, but being new to Git, I would say give the entire document a read.

I would have to review NetBeans to see how their Git plug-in works; it may not support the push to a remote repository (local commits only), but that would surprise me. I rarely work in an IDE that supports Git, so more often than not, my commits are done at the command-line.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I believe it will help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want like "your post say" to change your git remote repository on localhost you need to do this:

First you need to see your actual repository with this:

```
git remote -v
```

Then you need to set your new repository url:

```
git remote set-url <name> <newurl>
```

Example:

```
git remote set-url origin http://newserver/myproject.git
```

You can see the change with this command again:

```
git remote -v
```

That's all...