# Failed Deploy Apps to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying push my rails apps to heroku, first create heroku account and then on command prompt

- git init
- git add .
- git commit -m "init"
- heroku login and then push ssh
- heroku create mycvdemo
- git push heroku master

> 

```
C:\Sites\mycv>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 253, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (228/228), done.
Writing objects:   8% (21/253), 208.00 KiB | 3 KiB/s
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
C:\Sites\mycv>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 253, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (228/228), done.
Write failed: The connection was abortediB | 3 KiB/s
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mycvdemo.git'
```

I always getting this error when 8% writing object.

Comment: make sure that `'git@heroku.com:mycvdemo.git'` is the proper location.  i'm ignorant with Heroku, but with github, you usually have to put a username in there. like, `'git@heroku.com:username/mycvdemo.git'`

Comment: have you done `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:mycvdemo.git` ?

Comment: @RajarshiDas git remote automatically added when I run `heroku create`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you're missing a step here:

- git init
- git add .
- git commit -m "init"
- **git push origin master**
- heroku login and then push ssh
- heroku create mycvdemo
- git push heroku master

You can only push things to Heroku that have already been pushed to git.  Commits are only local.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745097/2128691) is a good explanation (with a picture!)

Comment: Are you sure I should run "git push origin master" for deploy to heroku? I have try step by step from heroku article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

Comment: I have done it, yes.  It's possible there are other issues (because heroku is tricky), so if you run `git push origin master` it might not fix it completely - but it also won't hurt anything.  It only pushes your the data in your local repository to your git hub.  Check out that picture I linked to