# What is the difference between git commit and git commit-tree

Tags: git, commit

I am reading about git objects: blob, tree, commit, tag. In order to have a better understanding of how git works, I tried some low level command like `write-tree` and `commit-tree`.

1. `mkdir test; cd test` --> `git init`
2. I create a file and `git add file`. I can see a blob and tree object are generated in `.git/objects`
3. `git write-tree` to print the current treeID
4. `git commit-tree treeID -m "commit a tree"` to commit this tree. After this operation, a commit object is generated and I can see it does contain author, date, etc. However, I can't check my commits using `git log`, the error is : `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`.

After above operations, when I run `git status`, I see the file is still in the index waiting for commit. What is the use of `commit-tree` and what's the difference between `commit-tree` and `commit'?

Comment: Have you read [this section](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) of the Pro Git book? It should be of interest to you, because it details how to create commits using "Plumbing" (i.e. low-level Git) commands.

Comment: You should probably edit your question and add the exact sequence of commands you used; that would make it easier for people here to pinpoint what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[git-commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) - Record changes to the repository

Stores the current contents of the index in a new commit along with a log message from the user describing the changes.

> git commit "records changes to the repository"

Diagrammatic representation of `git-commit` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745076/what-are-the-differences-between-git-commit-and-git-push) at SO

[git-commit-tree](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) - Create a new commit object

Creates a new commit object based on the provided tree object and emits the new commit object id on `stdout`.

> This is usually not what an end user wants to run directly. Creates a
>   new commit object based on the provided tree object and emits the new
>   commit object id on stdout. The log message is read from the standard
>   input, unless `-m` or `-F` options are given.

Comment: both `git commit` and  `git commit-tree` create commit object and can accept user message, however, `git commit` with snapshots the index HEAD, but `git commit-tree` will not guarantee the commit object is from HEAD index, it could be from any (sub)tree of the whole tree structure, am I right? so after `git commit-tree`, if I have a api to put certain commit on the HEAD, then the result will be like `git commit` ?

Comment: This answer is technically accurate but I think it doesn't stress an incredibly important point. `git-commit-tree` is a low level command which commits a single tree object but does not perform any of the follow-up reference and Head work that `git-commit` does. If you are manually performing `git commit-tree` commands without the follow-up reference work, you could easily create an unreachable tree which would be removed by the Git garbage cleaner. See [Git from the bottom up](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/1-Repository/4-how-trees-are-made.html) pages 8-10 for more info.

Answer (score 2):

git-commit(1) is the high-level command that you want to use almost all
of the time. git-commit-tree(1) is a lower-level command which is not a
daily-use command.

git-commit(1) is used when you commit new changes interactively. But I
guess I don’t have to elaborate on that.

git-commit-tree(1) is useful when you:

1. Want to explicitly pick the parents of a commit
2. You already have a *tree* for the commit

Say that I want to effectively “squash” all the commits in the repo down
to a single commit. But “squash” is a rebase operation which is
excessive since it combines changes, and I don’t need to combine any
changes since I already know what snapshot I want—the current
one. So:[1] [2]

```
$ git commit-tree -m Init HEAD^{tree}
1a875b50b508c70e44a4e6300fd80f580aed3d99
```

(That becomes a parentless commit since I didn’t specify any parents with
`-p`.)

That’s the SHA1 of the commit. I better put it on a
branch so that the garbage collector won’t collect it a few months from
now.

```
$ git branch new-start 1a875b50b508c70e44a4e6300fd80f580aed3d99
```

Another thing you can do is create whatever history you want using
existing commits and their trees. Say for example that I want to make a
history of the Git repository which only consists of versions `v1.0.0`,
`v2.0.0`, and `v2.40.0` and call the branch `small-git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git/ git-repo
cd git-repo
first=$(git commit-tree -m v1 v1.0.0^{tree})
second=$(git commit-tree -p $first -m v2 v2.0.0^{tree})
third=$(git commit-tree -p $second -m v2.40.0 v2.40.0^{tree})
git branch small-git $third
```

You can verify with this (all diffs should be empty):

```
$ # While on `small-git`
$ git diff v2.40.0
$ git diff @^ v2.0.0
$ git diff @^^ v1.0.0
```

#### Notes

1. See `man gitrevisions` for the `^{tree}` syntax
2. This can be accomplished by way of other means, like e.g. `git checkout --orphan new-start && git commit -m Init`. So it’s not like
   you need this command to do it.

Comment: "I better check it out and put it on a branch" No, you do not need to check out the commit merely in order to "put it on a branch."

Comment: Also please stop using `checkout` and switch to `switch`. `checkout` has checked out.

Comment: Ok. I’ve dropped the “check out branch” part. Thanks.

Comment: I’ve dropped the regular `git checkout` (not `checkout --orphan`) uses now in order to avoid controversy. ;)