# Says it commits, but in GitHub it doesn't show up

Tags: git, github

I just installed rails on an Ubuntu machine. I set up git and made an ssh key to link to my account. I made a repository to commit to, and made a sample project to test with called first_app. When I make commits it says it was all committed, but I go to github and it isn't there. I want to put my project up there, but it doesn't have the connection for some reason. I've googled around and I'm not seeing anything so it must be some stupid thing I did. Is there a way I can check that everything is configured right?

Edit: Tried to set the remote address, but it was already right. It has the correct URL.

Edit2: Here is what came up in the terminal:

```
jonny@MM061-JD:~/first_app$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:JonnyDoeInWisco/first_app.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
jonny@MM061-JD:~/first_app$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:JonnyDoeInWisco/first_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:JonnyDoeInWisco/first_app.git (push)
```

Comment: Did you push your commit?

Comment: Yes I did, still nothing.

Comment: edit your question, @JonnyDoeInWisco and put the result of `$ cat .git/config` . it's possible that your remotes are configured improperly

Comment: Done. If I do a git log it also shows all the commits I've made.

Comment: now, you are sure that you have SSH setup?

Comment: It seems that actually worked to make a new ssh key. I think what I did was copy and pasted it wrong. Nothing I pushed before is there but my test file is.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to push your commits from your local repository to the remote repository:

```
$ git commit -m "your commit message"

$ git push origin <branch_name>
```

Substitute `<branch_name>` with the remote branch you are pushing to (i.e. `master` branch would be `$ git push origin master`).

With*out* pushing your commit, you should see a similar message when you run:

```
$ git status
```

Git will tell you that you have commits that you need to `push` to your remote.

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

#### Verify your remote repositories

If you are seeing an up-to-date status with your remote, you should verify you're actually pushing to the location/repo that you think you are:

```
$ git remote -v
```

Comment: I did this, it said that everything was up to date. But there's nothing on github.

Comment: @JonnyDoeInWisco Then you need to verify that your remote repo you are pushing to is the correct one you are expecting on GitHub: `$ git remote -v`

Answer (score 2):

You need to push your commits.

Try:

```
$ git push origin master
```

The reason for this, is because when you make a commit, it actually just commits to your "local repository".

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745076/what-are-the-differences-between-git-commit-and-git-push) on the difference between commits and pushes.

Answer (score 1):

With Git, you have to commit then push your changes. A commit is a local operation, while pushing actually sends your file to the remote repository.