# What is the difference between commits and pull requests

Tags: github

As I have read that commit means we have updated some code which has bugs and commited that code from where the issue is raised.
But what is a pull request.

Comment: See this to get an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745076/what-are-the-differences-between-git-commit-and-git-push

Comment: By the way, you can also commit code with no bugs on it.

Comment: @mmuzahid: Thank You for the link, it is a very well made and self explanatory diagram

Comment: @Evin1_, that's impossibru

Comment: What do we mean by committing code code with no bugs on it, what is it considered here

Comment: There are really good differences shown here below, others can read and benifit from it, why is the question downvoted

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A **pull request** is a way to 'commit' to a repository in which you don't have writing permissions.

The maintainers of that repository will check your request and decide if they either want to merge it with your code or leave the original as it is.

Comment: Thank you for this simple explanation.

Answer (score 30):

A **commit** is a discrete change to one or more files. It is a critical part of Git.

A **pull request** is a request to *merge* one or more commits into a different branch. It is not part of Git; it is only part of GitHub (and similar services like [BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/work-with-pull-requests-223220593.html)).

---

*See also [the Try Git tutorial](https://try.github.io), in which you can explore some of the differences farther.*

Comment: Thank you for bringing up and explaining this simple difference

Comment: If I need to commit on master then what is to be done

Comment: I think that you mean: if you need to commit on **origin** (your online version). Then you use push. https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/

Comment: As I have understood from your answer above, if we commit on a branch other than master on someone else's repository, than it is called pull request else if we commit in our own repository it is called push. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Not quite, if you want to update any branch of your own code with your changes you use **commit**, if you want to update any branch of someone else's code you use a **pull request**, if you want to update your online repository you use **push**, if you want to update your local repository with the online changes you use **pull**.

Comment: @Evin1_ Thanks for this comment evin. I've search the entire corpus of the internet for this

Comment: @Evin1_ if I do a commit to a branch that's not my own, does that permanently change the code file? Does the owner of the repository still have to accept the commit? Because I see some commits that are made by others and accepted or rejected by the owner of the repository. Am I making an error in my concepts of git/github?