# Everything Up-to-Date after git push command

Tags: git, github

Every time I tried to push it  says Everything up to date.
I have done updates previously but this time I think i made a mistake of writing "commit -a" instead of "commit -m". My Changes are staged but i am unable to push them Please Help.
My branch is main
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aChPb.png)
I want to push my updates to my repo

Answer (score 0):

> My Changes are staged but i am unable to push them

1. Commit your staged changes: `git commit -m "(Describe your changes here)"
2. Push your changes: `git push`

Have a look at [What are the differences between "git commit" and "git push"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745076/what-are-the-differences-between-git-commit-and-git-push) to understand the differences between staging, commiting and pushing.

Answer (score 0):

$ git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your `origin` is not set up, you can verify this with

`git remote -v`

Which should show something that looks like this:

```
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

If it doesn't you can look up how to set up your upstream `origin`.

But if you have not committed anything, nothing will get pushed. So just do `commit -m "COMMIT MESSAGE"` to commit after you have done `git add`.